# Is it possible to have many startup programs in the /etc/passwd file?

Tags: passwd

I already know that you can change the command executed for a specific user when he/she logs in. However, I do not know if you can have many start-up programs for the certain user. For example:

```
oqhax:x:1001:1001:Oqhax,,,:/home/oqhax:/bin/bash
```

The last section indicates the start-up program. Could you have more than one?

Thank-you

Comment: I am not sure now if you can separate each start-up program with a comma `,`

Comment: Why not just put the commands into your `.profile` startup script?

Comment: What is that file?

Comment: It's one of the files [automatically read by `bash`](http://stefaanlippens.net/bashrc_and_others/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man 5 passwd`:

> the program to run at login (if empty, use /bin/sh). If set to a non-existing executable, the user will be unable to login through login(1).

It doesn't say anything about running multiple programs, so no, you cannot put multiple programs there.

If you want to run multiple programs, you could conceivably create a script that runs the various programs, and use the script as the login shell.  That said, I don't fully understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: True, we could write all the programs that you want to execute (or commands) in a single one, and then execute that one. Thanks.